Kafka producer failing if one of zookeeper of broker fails in cluster
In my project, We are using kafka cluster with 5 zookeepers and 5 kafka brokers.
We are deploying zookeepers and kafka brokers in AKS cluster as statefulset.
The problem is any one of the zookeeper or kafka broker is down our application
is unable to produce any messages.
Below is our configuration
acks=all, 
request.timeout.ms=120000
retry.backoff.ms=5000
retries=3
linger.ms=250
max.insync.replicas=1

Topic Replication Factor : 3
Which property configuration helps to fix this issue.
Another problem is, after making all zookeepers and kafka brokers are up all messages are reprocessing.
Anyhelp will be greatly appreciated !!!

I doubt "any broker" would cause the issue. The acks would matter... But topic replication factor is most important. Please share it. For example, if you only have one replica, and it's on the broker that's unavailable, then nothing can produce to it. So, is the replication factor set to 5 and you need 5 acks?

@OneCricketeer replication factor is 3 only

If you use kafka-topics to describe the topic, do you see any partitions with less than 3 replicas?

what is the value of your min.insync.replicas?

@Vezir, its defaults to 1

@OneCricketeer all partitions are having exactly 3 replicas
